# Is there a Python equivalent to Perls 'package' keyword

Tags: python, namespaces, package

I'm wondering, if Python offers something similar to the *package* keyword in Perl. This keyword in effect creates a labeled namespace just anywhere in the code.

As far as I know, similar namespacing in Python is only possible by putting that code into a file and import it. But what if I have the code in a variable (e.g. read from some configuration file of my script)?

So in other words: Is there a way to eval Python code within an arbitrary namespace? In Perl I would just add

```
package my_pack;
```

at the beginning of that code and then eval it (within a namespace called *my_pack*)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 'some configuration file' can not assign a new variable; you have to assign a variable in your current script for that. so that should never lead to a name clash. or what is the specific code that creates the problem you refer to?

Comment: If I execute Python code (that I read from some configuration file for my script) using _eval_, this code can do anything including defining subroutines and variables.

Comment: ah, `eval`, agreed (and advised against!).

Comment: ug. That's an awful way of doing config files

Comment: I didn't want to bother you with all the details. My script is an app that allows the user to define buttons and other widgets in a configuration file. Each widget is associated with code, that the user can define, too. All those widgets are then shown in a GUI (that is thus user-configurable). So all I want to know is, if there's an equivalent to the package keyword?

Answer (score 0):

No, Perl's and Python's module systems work very differently. It is not possible to explicitly declare a specific Python module.

For a Python `eval()` or `exec()` that should execute the code within the context of a particular module, consider which aspects define this module for your purposes – the important aspect is likely that module's global variables. You can provide these explicitly, and capture the current environment via the `globals()` function. The environment is just a dict, which you can copy if you want to avoid modifications of the module's environment.

Comment: Thanks amon; I didn't understand that, but from the link I just posted it got clear to me.